# stroke-dashoffset not working in IOS chrome , safari

Tags: ios, css, d3.js, svg, smil

I have following keyframe for dash-animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 800;
}
0% {
    width: 0%;
}
100% {
    width: 50%;
}
}
```

It works fine in desktop chrome , firefox but not working in IOS safari and chrome. Can anyone suggest what am i doing wrong ?? , plus how to do the same thing in IE.

codepen link http://codepen.io/nitish1402/pen/jqJwZa

Comment: stroke-dashoffset is not animatable with CSS transitions and animations in Internet Explorer. It is animatable starting from Edge: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972274(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Those properties are not yet properly supported by Safari and Chrome on iOS!